# Homemade function inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, function, foreach

I have a large function that is based on a seven tier multidimensional array?

When I call the function in a for each like so

```
 foreach($items as $item) {
      makeItem($item, $items[$item]);
 }
```

It always fails why is this, although if I call them outside a foreach it is fine and works?

Comment: Not a single bit of this makes sense. Not one. Little. Bit.

Comment: Your first sentence is a statement that ends with a question mark. At that, the statement still doesn't make sense. You provided very little code, which isn't even valid PHP, and doesn't show the definition of a function. `function` is a keyword for defining, not calling functions.

Comment: @cgwebprojects: I'd suggest you stop being rude to people you're asking for free help. It doesn't encourage people to provide it.

Comment: oh my days, can you not clearly work out that `function` is in place of my own `function`, talk about nit picking

Comment: That is just too short you need provide a longer source code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, now that you've changed the code a bit... The problem is that when you use a foreach loop as you did, the loop variable isn't the index of the array, it's the element in the array. Your intent is still unclear to me, but you might want to do something like:

```
foreach($items as $key => $item) {
      makeItem($item, $items[$key]);
}
```

...which still wouldn't make sense because you would be passing in `$item` twice.

Comment: This worked except I did `foreach($items as $item => $value) {makeItem($item, $value);}` Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from the question, but if you are asking how to call your own function from inside a `foreach` loop and pass an item to that function, I believe that the code you are looking for is:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
        makeItem($item);
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

Why you have written the function three times in foreach.it can be called each time by writting it only once.or could you please describe or post some more code snipped .

Comment: Thanks @user, I want the function to be called with each value of the array.